# Getting count of repeated record occurrence in table

Tags: mysql, sql

In one of my table I store user details when ever he login into it.

I want to get repeated occurrence count  of each user. Means user x,y,z has logged in how many times.

```
SELECT count( id )
FROM user_stat
GROUP BY id
```

this just gives count value.

```
1     id        varchar(64)     latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
2     login     varchar(64)     latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
3     city      varchar(128)    latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
4     ip        varchar(128)    latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
5     logout    varchar(64)     latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
6     diff      varchar(64)     latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
7     username  varchar(64)     latin1_swedish_ci         Yes     NULL         Change Change     Drop Drop     More Show more actions
```

I want to count repeated occurrence details of each `id`. Means how many time person with id `x` has loged in.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> select count(login_id),login_id from `table_name` group by login_id;

```
Here login_id means users_login_id. try it
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want user info with count that how many time user logged in try below qry.
Try this :-

```
SELECT count( id ),username,id 
FROM user_stat
GROUP BY id
```

You will may add more column if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure What "details of each id" means. If "Means how many time person with id x" then following query is what you want.

```
SELECT id, count(id)
FROM user_stat
GROUP BY id
```

BTW, your table design is not **NORMALIZED**. It should be splitted two table. one for `login information`, one for `user info`, so below would be better.

```
user_tbl(user_id, user_name);
user_stat(user_id, login, city, ip, logout, diff)
```

Then your query can converted like this:

```
SELECT user_tbl.user_id, user_tbl.user_name,  COUNT(*)
FROM user_tbl JOIN user_stat USING(user_id)
GROUP BY user_tbl.user_id, user_tbl.user_name
```